# Placement of damping resistors, closer to driver or load?

Tags: pcb-design, emc

I'm connecting an FPGA and MCU and currently optimizing the placement. Does it matter if it's randomly placed? Should I place it like a series terminating resistor and strictly place it close to the driver(source)?[image]

Comment: Series termination resistors are placed close to the driver so that the ringing is contained to the short section between driver and resistor and basically increases the driver impedance as far as the rest of the line is concerned.

Comment: @DKNguyen Damping resistors are series termination resistors? I'm very strict with the placement of these but the terminology is messing with my brain.

Comment: They seem like the same thing to me in this context. They certainly look like the same thing from your schematic. Are you studying in English or another language? What is the difference between damping and series termination to you?

Comment: @DKNguyen English but I always called these series termination resistors never damping and wondering if it has a different purpose and I could be less strict with the placement. The PCB is very dense.

Comment: Well, to me damping means something a bit more general than series termination.

Answer (score 1):

By placing the 50_ohm resistor (for a 50 ohm line) very near the driven end, the initial voltage of the waveform (edge) on the line will be only 50% of the driver output voltage. The resistor + Line act as voltage_divider.

When the waveform arrives at the far end, the voltage will DOUBLE at that instant (required by the differential equation solution, for boundary conditions), and the far end will thus have a strong full amplitude voltage.

However the rest of the transmission line will still be at 50%.

As the reflection (from the open far end) travels back to the driver, the line progressively rises to full voltage.

Finally, after [2 * Delay], the entire line will be charged to full voltage, and as the reflection hits the 50_ohm resistor (assuming the Driver has LOW Zout), the reflection is exactly absorbed by the 50_ohm resistor.

Notice any circuits that monitor the waveform/edge will not see the final voltage until possibly as long as [2 * Delay].

Answer (score 0):

For SI purposes, the series resistors go near the source.  The idea is that the trace is a transmission line at heart, and will have a higher impedance than most drivers.  The addition of the resistor to the source impedance matches the total driving impedance to closer match that of the trace.